# Persist scroll event in partial view

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Is there a way to persist a scroll event in a partial View? I have a table that uses a scroll event that is needed after the ajax form post of the partial initiated within the index page. Is there a way to do this without putting the js in the partial view itself.

The scroll event is on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work-around such issues because the scroll event does not bubble, I put the scroll event and its needed elements inside an event that does bubble thus persisting the scroll event after an Ajax partial view is rendered.

Example:

```
        $("#parent").on("click", "#child", function (event) {

            $.ajax({
                url: urlForPost,
                type: "POST",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15"
            }).done(function (allData) {
                //First Remove white space for IE9 
                var expr = new RegExp('>[ \t\r\n\v\f]*<', 'g');
                allData = allData.replace(expr, '><');

                $("#parent").html(allData);
                ResizeContent();
              $("#id1").scroll(function () {
               $("#id2").scrollLeft($("#id1").scrollLeft());
           });
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
          }
```